# Progress bar css styling issue

Tags: html, css

I have some difficulties styling my progress bar when I include links in an unordered list:

without links it is perfectly fine:

[image]

with links it is removing the progess bar:

[image]

I tried styling the a href in css, mainly playing with:

```
    display:table-cell
```

since imo table-cell is actually creating the progress line connections, but that did not work out so far. My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/m7oak1wy/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done, what you have asked.

Please check the given below snippet.

Thanks

```css
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done {
  border-color: yellowgreen ;
}
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
}


ol.etapier {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
ol.etapier a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
ol.etapier a li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
ol.etapier li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

ol.etapier li a {
 color: inherit;
}

ol.etapier li {
    color: silver; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}
ol.etapier li.done {
    color: black;
}

ol.etapier li:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7.5px;

    color: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
}
ol.etapier li.done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
}
ol.etapier li.todo:before {
    content: " " ;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ol class="etapier">
    <a href=""><li class="done">1.</li></a>
    <li class="done">2.</li>
    <li class="todo">3.</li>
    <li class="done">4.</li>
    <li class="done">5.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

`OL`(/`UL`) cannot contain other children but `LI` (you have some `a` in there).

A secret? Never style `LI` elements beyond needed.
Just style enough to set them horizontally / vertically, and move on styling their inner elements.
I.e. instead, if you style the inner `A` elements  you can gain a larger clickable UI element (= great UI)

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7oak1wy/17/)

**HTML**

```
<ol class="etapier">
    <li class="done"><a href="">1.</a></li>
    <li class="done"><a href="">2.</a></li>
    <li class="todo"><a href="">3.</a></li>
    <li class="done"><a href="">4.</a></li>
    <li class="done"><a href="">5.</a></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS :**

```
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done {
  border-color: yellowgreen ;
}
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
}


ol.etapier {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
ol.etapier li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

ol.etapier li a {
    color: inherit;
}

ol.etapier li {
    color: silver; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}
ol.etapier li.done {
    color: black;
} 
ol.etapier li a { position :relative; }
ol.etapier li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -23px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:-5px;

    color: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    border-radius: 15px;

}
ol.etapier li.done a:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: green
}
ol.etapier li.todo a:before {
    content: " " ;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I want to include the green line + circle in the a href as well, i.e. it has to be clickable. Should have said that in OP.

Comment: @klabanus `7.5px` will not work (exactly). px are not `%` Round to integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="etapier">
<li class="done"><a href="">1.</a></li>
<li class="done"><a href="">2.</a></li>
<li class="todo"><a href="">3.</a></li>
<li class="done"><a href="">4.</a></li>
<li class="done"><a href="">5.</a></li>
</ol>


 you use anchor in li this will fine to work
```

Answer (score 0):

check with this below code as you required and it may help you.

```css
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done {
  border-color: yellowgreen ;
}
/* CHANGE COLOR HERE */ 
ol.etapier li.done:before {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
}


ol.etapier {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
ol.etapier li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

ol.etapier li a {
 color: inherit;
}

ol.etapier li {
    color: silver; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}
ol.etapier li.done {
    color: black;
}

ol.etapier li:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7.5px;

    color: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
}
ol.etapier li.done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
}
ol.etapier li.todo:before {
    content: " " ;
    background-color: white;
}
.etapier li a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 45%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="etapier">
    <li class="done">1.<a href=""></a></li>
    <li class="done">2.<a href=""></a></li>
    <li class="todo">3.</li>
    <li class="done">4.<a href=""></a></li>
    <li class="done">5.<a href=""></a></li>
</ol>
```